# Rails 3 migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Current migration:

```
t.string   "email", :default => "", :null => false
add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
```

I want to create a new migration to remove the `:null => false` requirement and also remove the `default => ""` for `email`. Also, I would like to change the index to remove `:unique => true`. What's the syntax?

Comment: Have you already performed this migration? If not, you can just edit it to remove the fields you don't want.

Comment: Migration is already performed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't done much with indices, and there doesn't seem to be a change_index method on `ActiveRecord::Migration`, but you can try something like this:

```
class ChangeUserStuff < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :users, :email, :default => "", :null => true
    remove_index :users, :column => :email
    add_index :users, :email
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :users, :email, :default => "", :null => false
    remove_index :users, :column => :email
    add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
  end
end
```

There was some funny behavior regarding changing `:null` options, but I believe setting them to `true` instead of omitting should handle it.

Comment: The "available transformations" section [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) has the full syntax for removing indices.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer to use the proper `:column => :column_name` syntax.

Comment: BTW `remove_index :users, :column => :email` should also be `remove_index :users, :email`.

Comment: According to documentation: `remove_index(table_name, :column => column_name): Removes the index specified by column_name.` Is this incorrect? Once again, have never used add/remove_index before.

Comment: Dunno, that could be for older version of Rails, for 3.x, it's what I said.

Comment: In your example, change_column also needs the column type.  `change_column :users, :email, :string, default: "", null: true`